# Creating vector of names from list and nested list in R

Tags: r, list, for-loop

I have a nested list and want to create a character vector (for file paths/outputs) by iterating over the elements of the list and the sub-elements of each element in R. The list has 174 elements, and each of those elements has five sub-elements (the names of these sub-elements are consistent across each element of the list).

See, for example, the following nested list, which has two elements with five sub-elements each:

```
iter1 <- list(item1 = "a", item2 = "b",item3 = "c", item4 = "d",item5 = "e")
iter2 <- list(item1 = "a", item2 = "b",item3 = "c", item4 = "d",item5 = "e")
All <- list(iter1 = iter1, iter2 = iter2)
```

The desired vector output would follow the following structure (assuming all outputs are being saved in a folder labeled, 'output':

```
[1] "output/iter1_item1.png"  
[2] "output/iter1_item2.png"  
[3] "output/iter1_item3.png"  
[4] "output/iter1_item4.png"  
[5] "output/iter1_item5.png"  
[6] "output/iter2_item1.png"...etc.
```

Unless I'm mistaken, the length of the character vector should be 870 (174*5).

I am very close with the following code:

```
for(i in 1:length(All)){
output_names <- paste0("output/",names(All[i]),"_",names(All[[i]]),".png")}
```

It produces a character vector with the length of 5 - essentially, the first element with each of the five sub-elements. I would like the code to iterate over each element so that the rest of them are captured as well (the above reproducible example only contains two elements, but my original list contains 175 elements).

Thanks in advance for any help on this issue.

Comment: @markus thanks for your feedback - I have tried to add a reproducible example with expected output. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Like so: `paste0("output/", chartr(".", "_", names(unlist(All))), ".png")` ?

Comment: @markus thanks so much - that's really helpful and definitely addresses the issue. I will read up on chartr. 

One additional question - how do I handle this if the item1, item2, etc. are all data frames with rows and columns (and I only want to capture the name of the sub-element, not the individual parts, which I think unlist does)? I'm having a hard time constructing a reproducible example, but if I were to use your code on the larger list, it outputs more items than needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the example data, you can repeat the top-level names the appropriate number of times, and `sapply` over the list to ger the bottom level names.

```
paste0('output/', rep(names(All), lengths(All)), '_', sapply(All, names), '.png')

#  [1] "output/iter1_item1.png" "output/iter1_item2.png" "output/iter1_item3.png"
#  [4] "output/iter1_item4.png" "output/iter1_item5.png" "output/iter2_item1.png"
#  [7] "output/iter2_item2.png" "output/iter2_item3.png" "output/iter2_item4.png"
# [10] "output/iter2_item5.png"
```

If your sublists have different lengths you need `unlist(lapply(All, names))` instead of `sapply(All, names)`.

Comment: Perfect - thank you so much! That definitely addresses the problem with the entire list, particularly the fact that the sub-elements have dimensions. I will read up on sapply and rep - appreciate the help.